# Passing Value from string.xml from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android

The value in string.xml file...

```
 <string name="bangla_history_2ndpoint">SOME VALUE </string>
```

From this activity i am trying to pass value to another activity ... by using putextra

```
Intent ptwo=new Intent("com.powergroupbd.victoryday.of.bangladesh.HISTORYDESCRIPTION");
            ptwo.putExtra("header", R.string.bangla_history_2ndpoint);


            startActivity(ptwo);
```

Then get the value in this activity ...

But it is not getting the value from the string.xml  file...

```
text_point = getIntent().getStringExtra("header");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text_point, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But it is toasting blank ....

Please give a solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're trying to retrieve a `String`, but what you're passing in as extra is actually the resource identifier of it, an `int`. Either put an actual string as extra, or retrieve an int on the receiving end to fix this.

```
// put:
ptwo.putExtra("header", R.string.bangla_history_2ndpoint);
// get:
int extraResourceId = getIntent().getIntExtra("header");
text_point = getString(extraResourceId);
```

Or:

```
// put:
ptwo.putExtra("header", getString(R.string.bangla_history_2ndpoint));
// get:
text_point = getIntent().getStringExtra("header");
```

Comment: Thanx A lot for your valuable solution.